# Uninstall Ubuntu (dual boot)

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning

I am trying to uninstall Ubuntu 16.04 and re-install it using VirtualBox. I had installed (dual boot) it using an USB stick. Now I have a problem in locating the partition to be deleted.

[image: This pic shows the disk management page from Windows side.]

[image: This pic shows the disk management from Ubuntu side.]

from ubuntu side, I got to know that partition 7 and 8 are of Ubuntu while others are of Windows. So, should I delete that on Ubuntu? If I delete that will it effect my windows.
 If I have to delete on windows, which partition on disk manager on pic 1 should I delete?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it is partition 7, as it's just before swap partition (classical Ubuntu installation), and seems to be the only one in ext4 type.
To be sure, open a terminal, as 'root' and type :
- fdisk -l : to get all partition tables
- mount : to see where your Ubuntu master partition (called "/") is mounted.

Answer (score 0):

The partition in which your ubuntu os is installed is 7. The file format of the partition is EXT4 which is for linux.

Comment: So should I delete that partition on Ubuntu?

Comment: If you want to remove ubuntu, just delete the partition 7.